# Update text in label

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have a label on page which I want to show realtime time & date.

I have label on page using C#/Asp.net

Comment: By realtime, do you mean you want to create a clock which `ticks` on the webpage? Like this website http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/city.html?n=136

Comment: Even though some were able to determine what you were trying to ask, this question really isn't clear enough to remain open. If you can improve it, I'll be happy to re-open it for you.

Comment: Sounds obvious to me, looks like it was just missing the javascript tag.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a job for JavaScript try this:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function display_c(){
var refresh=1000; // Refresh rate in m seconds
mytime=setTimeout('display_ct()',refresh)
}

function display_ct() {
var strcount
var x = new Date()
document.getElementById('ct').innerHTML = x;
tt=display_c();
}
</script>
</head>

<body onload=display_ct();>
<span id='ct' ></span>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

there is a text property of label you can set it.
`label.text = DateTime.Now` or `System.DateTime.Now.ToString().Trim()`

Answer (score 0):

```
lbl.Text = System.DateTime.Now.ToString().Trim();
```